# Adicionar botões nas linhas da tabela

Tags: jquery, html5, json

Estou usando: https://www.dynatable.com/ e com ela estou conseguindo criar a tabela e carregar os dados json.
O problema é que não to conseguindo adicionar mais uma coluna com as ações de editar e excluir, por exemplo. Onde seriam 2 botões.
O back é com Java.

Comment: cara nunca usei esse plugin/API, mas faz o seguinte posta os códigos do que você consegui até agora, dai eu dou uma olhada se consigo te ajudar

Comment: @SneepSNinjA pelo que to entendendo, é nesse arquivo deles que deveria conseguir fazer essa personalização, que no caso seria adicionar mais 1 coluna com 2 botões, um pra editar e um pra excluir https://jsfiddle.net/43d0uz9t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faz assim:

```
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
dataset: {
    records:
            [
                {
                    "band": "Weezer",
                    "song": "El Scorcho",
                    "editar":"<button onclick='javascript:editar();'>editar</button>",
                    "excluir":"<button onclick='javascript:excluir();'>excluir</button>"
                },
                {
                    "band": "Chevelle",
                    "song": "Family System",
                    "editar":"<button onclick='javascript:editar();'>editar</button>",
                    "excluir":"<button onclick='javascript:excluir();'>excluir</button>"
                }
            ]
}
});
```

Caso você esteja recebendo o json de um ajax, lá onde o json é gerado terá que montar os elementos (botoes do HTML) junto no json como o exemplo acima, ai é só você implementar a parte do javascript para editar/excluir, se tiver dúvidas nessa parte é só sinalizar.

**EDIT:**

Não pediu mas como no site não tem um exemplo fácil para manipular diretamente o json que já esta em uso pelo plugin achei até necessário postar como fazer para excluir um item, com base nesse exemplo o editar seria na mesma linha de raciocínio, que é editar o json, excluindo ou alterando um registro, depois carregar ele novamente no plugin segue exemplo:

```
var MeuArray = 
        [
            {            
                "idx":0,
                "band": "Weezer",
                "song": "El Scorcho",
                "editar": "<button onclick='javascript:editar(0);'>editar</button>",
                "excluir": "<button onclick='javascript:excluir(0);'>excluir</button>"
            },
            {   
                "idx":1,
                "band": "Chevelle",
                "song": "Family System",
                "editar": "<button onclick='javascript:editar(1);'>editar</button>",
                "excluir": "<button onclick='javascript:excluir(1);'>excluir</button>"
            }
        ];
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({ dataset: { records: MeuArray } });

function excluir(index){
    for(var i=0; i<MeuArray.length; i++){
        var obj = MeuArray[i];
        if(obj.idx == index){ 
            MeuArray.splice(i, 1);            
            break;
        }        
    }    
    var dynatable = $('#my-final-table').data('dynatable');
    dynatable.settings.dataset.originalRecords = MeuArray;
    dynatable.process();    
}
```